# Is there any way to push down a filter when running "dbutils.fs.ls" in a Databricks notebook?

Tags: filter, azure-blob-storage, databricks, dbutils

I have a container in an Azure blob storage that contains around 10,000,000 CSV and Zip files.

I want to use "dbutils.fs.ls" in a Databricks notebook to get a list of files. However, after running the command and waiting for more than 30 minutes, I got the below error:

```
The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached.
```

I have used a multi-node cluster:

- Driver: Standard_D4ds_v5
- Worker: Standard_D4ds_v5
- Min Workers: 2
- Max Workers: 8

It seems that the cluster cannot handle getting the list of all files. I was wondering if I could push down a filter on filenames and get the list of files after filtering. I am interested in files starting with "Energy". In this way, it might be possible to get a list of desired files without the above error.

Comment: Did you try`ls("Energy*")`?

Comment: No, dbutils doesn't handle wildcards...

Comment: @OneCricketeer, Thanks. I need to pass the container path to this command like "files = dbutils.fs.ls(f"wasbs://{container_name}@{storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Azure SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-containerclient-list-blobs) instead:

```
for blob in container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with="Energy"):
  ...
```

`list_blobs` can filter results, moreover it returns a generator instead of materializing all results upfront.